# What will be the name of the windows phone app in windows phone app store?

Tags: windows-phone

What will be the name of the windows phone app in the app store??
Either the **alias name** which we gave while submitting or the name of the **xap file**?? or the one given in **WMAppManifest.xml**

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a name while you're submitting your app to the store. That name is your application's store name. Xap file name doesn't matter, you can give a randomly name to xap (like xyahsuthr.xap:))